# In Rails, how can I execute a block upon database new entry, and insert that block result as a parameter?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, lambda, model, block

Basically, I have a random 10 digit number generator

```
shuffle=lambda {(1..10).to_a.map {|i| (1..9).to_a.sample}.join}
```

and I have a model User that has name:string, account:string

What I would love to know, is how every time I create a new user
User.create(name: "John") I would like shuffle to be #called and inserted into the :account that is associated with "John".

Answer (score 0):

You can use [callbacks](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_callbacks.html)

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  before_create :set_account

  private
  def set_account
    self.account = "%010d" % rand(10**10) # this will generate a 10 digit string with leading 0s
  end
end
```

Comment: Much appreciated sir. Also, what does the private mean?